# New-SPWeb : Cannot find an SPSite object that contains the following Id or Url:

Tags: 2013, powershell, exception

While Running Following command:

```
New-SPWeb -url "https://xyz.com/sites/" -name "apple" -template STS#0
```

I received following error:

```
    New-SPWeb : Cannot find an SPSite object that contains the following Id or Url: 
https://xyz.com/sites/.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-SPWeb -url "https://xyz.com/sites/" -name ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share....SPCmdletNewWeb:SPCmdletNewWeb) [New-SPWeb], SPCmdletPipeBindE 
   xception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletNewWeb
```

I am farm administrator and have access to content db of the server.

Comment: Under which account you are running the powershell script? try to run with Farm admin account(account running the Timer services) and also run the powershell console as Adminsitrator.

Comment: `https://xyz.com/sites` isn't any site collection.. the correction site collection would be `https://xyz.com/` or `https://xyz.com/sites/sitecollectionName` correct the URL of the site collection and command should work

Comment: Your site collection name is not correct

Comment: I want to create site under root site https://xyz.com/Sites of named apple. how do it do it then using powershell

Answer (score 2):

SPWeb is a **subsite** inside a site collection.

But you want to create a new *root site* under a managed path, so have to create a new site collection.

With a new site collection, a new SPWeb is also generated as the root site.

```
New-SPSite https://example.com/sites/apple -Name "Apple" -Template "STS#0"
```

PS: New-SPWeb is used, if you want to create another subsite in your **existing** site collection.

Answer (score 1):

To provision site with powershell use following command:

```
New-SPWeb –url <new site url> -name <new site name> -template <template name>
```

For example it should be :

```
New-SPWeb –url http://vsharepoint/HyperV -name "All about HyperV" 
-template STS#0
```

So in your case "https://xyz.com/sites/" is not a valid name under which site can be created.

You can also refer and use following scripts to create sites:

https://spcreatesitesfromcsv.codeplex.com/

Comment: In Central Admin i have option to select web application name https://xyz.com which will give me an option to create site inside the https://xyz.com/sites managed path. thats what i am doing here and i want to create new site under that managed path as "apple"

Answer (score 0):

New-SPWeb creates a subsite, if you want to create Apple under /sites it is a site collection and you have to use New-SPSite

```
New-SPSite https://yoursite.com/sites/apple -OwnerAlias "DOMAIN\user" -Name Apple
```

[Check this link for more information on this Powershell command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607937%28v=office.15%29.aspx)